# ccsprite texture slide

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is their any way to change the color of a ccsprite from one end of the sprite to the other smoothly within a precise time frame.  I am trying to implement a smoothly moving torchlight effect on tiles.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a complete way to do it, but my first port of call would be to look at CCGradientLayer

Comment: I think I'm going to first try using an animation, since the sprites are only 32x32.  Their will be a performance hit, but acceptable I think.  Thank you.